# Difference between complexity logn and log(sqrt(n))

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

considering

**log(sqrt(n)) = (1/2)log(n)**

And if for asymptotic analysis we don't consider the constant terms 
so, is O(log(sqrt(n))) is as good as O(log(n))?

As per my understanding log(sqrt(n)) will grow slowly in comparison to log(n) if we increase the size of n. But I am not able understand the glitch in moving power of (1/2) at front?
Is it just this that factor 1/2 only slows down the rate?

consider the case when we have log(n*n) represented as 2log(n) , and log(n)?

Comment: Why not visualizing both graphs in wolframalpha?

Comment: @bobah maybe codenamefreak47 wants to know how to work things out for themselves

Answer (score 8):

It is the same asymptotically:

```
O(log(sqrt(n))) = O(log(n^1/2)) = O(1/2 log(n)) = O(log(n))
```

Answer (score 5):

```
Time(A) = log n

Time(B) = log sqrt(n) = log n^(1/2) = 1/2 log n
```

**Asymptotically the same**

```
O(Time(A)) = O(log n)

O(Time(B)) = O(1/2 log n) = O(log n)

O(Time(A)) = O(Time(B))
```

**Insignificantly different**

```
Time(A) = 1   * log n

Time(B) = 1/2 * log n

Time(A) > Time(B)

Time(A) = 2 * Time(B)
```

**Conclusion**

```
log n = 2 log sqrt(n)
```

Although the difference between `log n` and `log sqrt(n)` is in insignificant, `log n` will always take double the amount of time `log sqrt(n)` takes

**Visual**

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You are right, O(log(sqrt(n))) is the same as O(log(n)) by the reasoning given in your question.

Answer (score 1):

The big-O notation ignores any constant multiplier.

`O(500000.N)` is `O(N)` and is `O(0.00001.N)`.

For the same reason, `O(Log(Sqrt(N)))` is `O(1/2.Log(N))` is `O(Log(N))`, and that in any base.

The big-O notation is not about the speed of your program, it is about the growth of the running time as `N` increases.